# Using regular expression in string replacement

Tags: r, regex, csv, replace

I have a broken csv file that I am attempting to read into R and repair using a regular expression.

The reason it is broken is that it contains some fields which include a comma but does not wrap those fields in double quotes. So I have to use a regular expression to find these fields, and wrap them in double quotes.

Here is an example of the data source:

```
DataField1,DataField2,Price
ID1,Value1,
ID2,Value2,$500.00
ID3,Value3,$1,250.00
```

So you can see that in the third row, the Price field contains a comma but it is not wrapped in double quotes. This breaks the read.table function.

My approach is to use readLines and str_replace_all to wrap the price with commas in double quotes. But I am not good at regular expressions and stuck.

```
vector <- read.Lines(file)
vector_temp <- str_replace_all(vector, ",\\$[0-9]+,\\d{3}\\.\\d{2}", ",\"\\$[0-9]+,\\d{3}\\.\\d{2}\"")
```

I want the output to be:

```
DataField1,DataField2,Price
ID1,Value1,
ID2,Value2,$500.00
ID3,Value3,"$1,250.00"
```

With this format, I can read into R.
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra facilities in the stringi or stringr packages do not seem needed. `gsub` seems perfectly suited for this. You just need understand about capture-groups with paired parentheses (brackets to Brits) and the use of the double-backslash_n convention for referring to capture-group matches in the replacement argument:

```
txt <- "DataField1,DataField2,Price, extra
ID1,Value1, , 
ID2,Value2,$500.00,
ID3,Value3,$1,250.00, o"

vector<- gsub("([$][0-9]{1,3}([,]([0-9]{3})){0,10}([.][0-9]{0,2}))" , "\"\\1\"", readLines(textConnection(txt)) )

> read.csv(text=vector)
  DataField1 DataField2     Price extra
1        ID1     Value1                
2        ID2     Value2   $500.00      
3        ID3     Value3 $1,250.00     o
```

You are putting quotes around specific sequence of digits possibly repeated(commas digits) and possible period and 2 digits . There might be earlier SO questions about formatting as "currency".

Comment: Your RE assumes the field ends with a new line (implied by the question, so ok). Also the escape on the double quote is to avoid premature end of string, so using single quotes avoids the need. Maybe `gsub('(\\$.*)', '"\\1"', vector)` is a cleaner implementation?

Comment: Right. If another field follows the matched expression, the comma gets wrapped up. I guess I need to do a more complex version.

Comment: This is the approach I used. I knew that there must be some kind of concept like capture groups, but didn't know how to search for information. Looks like I need to read up on them.

Answer (score 3):

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection(object="DataField1,DataField2,Price
ID1,Value1,
ID2,Value2,$500.00
ID3,Value3,$1,250.00"))

library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)

stri_split_regex(lines, ",", n=3, simplify=TRUE) %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  docxtractr::assign_colnames(1) 
##   DataField1 DataField2     Price
## 1        ID1     Value1          
## 2        ID2     Value2   $500.00
## 3        ID3     Value3 $1,250.00
```

from there you can `readr::write_csv()` or `write.csv()`

Comment: Perhaps write your own answer? `?stri_split_regex` wld immediately show what `n=3` does. The rest is just gravy. The OP wld have grok'd the rest after the `stri_` bit (they grok regex so that implies some ability). No real performance hit `fixed` vs `regex` for that file so muscle memory won out.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions:

**1) read.pattern** This uses `read.pattern` in the gsubfn package to read in a file (assumed to be called `sc.csv`) such that the capture groups, i.e. the parenthesized portions, of the pattern are the fields.  This will read in the file and process it all in one step so it is not necessary to use `readLines` first.

`^(.*?),` that begins the pattern will match everything from the start until the first comma.  Then `(.*?),` will match to the next comma and finally `(.*)$` will match everything else to the end.  Normally `*` is greedy, i.e. it matches as much as it can, but the question mark after it makes it ungreedy.  We needed to specify `perl=TRUE` so that it uses perl regular expressions since by default gsubfn uses tcl regular expressions based on Henry Spencer's regex parser which does not support `*?` .  If you would rather have character columns instead of factor then add the `as.is=TRUE` argument to `read.pattern`.

The final line of code removes the `$` and `,` characters from the Price column and converts it to numeric.  (Omit this line if you actually want it formatted.)

```
library(gsubfn)

DF <- read.pattern("sc.csv", pattern = "^(.*?),(.*?),(.*)$", perl = TRUE, header = TRUE)
DF$Price <- as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", DF$Price)) ##
```

giving:

```
> DF
 DataField1 DataField2 Price
1        ID1     Value1    NA
2        ID2     Value2   500
3        ID3     Value3  1250
```

**2) sub**  This uses very simple regular expression (just a single character match) and no packages.  Using `vector` as defined in the question this replaces the first two commas with semicolons.  Then it can be read in using `sep = ";"`

```
read.table(text = sub(",", ";", sub(",", ";", vector)), header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Add the line marked ## in (1) if you want numeric prices.